# Arduino Nano USB Serial Bypass

Tags: serial, arduino-nano

I have a Nano clone here, that sporadically fails to get detected by my banana pi. This is annoying, because it works for days and hours, but fails to work randomly.

The Nano gets it's own power via `VIN` and thus should have enough power.

I thought of bypassing the FTDI and make a Serial connection via 2 Wires. Alternatively: Is there a way to force the arduino to use external Power over USB. I have the feeling, the the arduino wrongly decides, that USB is the better power source and uses it, causing the errors ( `device not accepting address 21, error -62` )

P.S.: There is also a touch-screen connected to the banana pi via USB. Whatever port I use, It works and never failed. Just the Nano fails from time to time.

Comment: Many arduino type boards have a resistor between the USB-serial function and the main ATmega, potentially allowing an external "strong" driver to take over.  But the Banana pi may not (?) support 5v I/O.  Your best bet is probably to locate and remove that resistor, then build a level shifter with resistors.  For safety you could put one on both transmit and receive, since the the receive pin could potentially be misprogrammed as a 5v output.  As for the USB, is your "arduino" and especially its USB-serial chip real, or fake?

Comment: One could lower the 5V line from arduino to the banan pi with 2 resistors (voltage divider)/. That would be it.

Comment: Minimal recommended voltage for `Vin` is 7 Volt!

Comment: @ansi_lumen It's probably easier to just remove the 5v wire from the USB entirely, or remove the diode `D1` from the [board](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoNano30Schematic.pdf) (the black two pin component on the bottom)

Comment: Is it truly an FT232 on it, or the el-cheapo Chinese CHwhatever it is?

Comment: @Gerben. Shure? Think there is no voltage regulator for Xto5V on the Nano. The chip takes 5V. I think 7V would kill it.

Comment: @Majenko Package looks okay. Flashed it with `ftdi_eeprom` and it still works.

Comment: @Gerben To remove the 5V line from the USB is also a good idea. But I think, I'll be faster with soldering a serial connection cable with voltage divider. This way I would get a free port for other stuff.

Comment: Assuming that USB-power was the actual problem here.

Comment: I can't comment so have to post this as an answer, but perhaps connect the GNDs together? But I also see that someone else mentioned the whole el-cheapo concept, too. I have noticed differences between boards sometimes, and exchanging them with one from a known supplier sometimes fixes my problems.

Comment: @ansi_lumen did you ever solve your problem. If so, could you post the answer here please?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question

The arduino in question was broken. Shortly after asking I was not even able to connect it to my PC successfully. I replaced it with a new one and everything runs smoothly now for months.

Since this unit survived a whole product development-process I am not surprised at all. In fact I had three and expected one to get killed in action.